# How can I horizontally expand my footer div?

Tags: html, css

I want my footer div to take all the horiziontal space available. Here is my code, but it doesn't work. Hope you can help me!

**HTML**

```html
<div id=footer>
     NewCom France Copyright &copy 2020  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#footer {
          padding: 12px;
          background-color: #999999;
          text-align: center;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0;
          text-align: center;
          margin: 0 auto;
          line-height: auto;
}
```

Comment: is your footer div inside an other div ?

Comment: No, my footer is not inside another div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin on a fixed-position element does nothing, and margin on `body` won't affect it either, as `position: fixed` positions an element relative to the *viewport*, outside of the flow of any other elements.

To ensure full width, a fixed-position element will need to have its `right` and `left` properties set.

```css
#footer {
  /* positioning */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;

  /* other styling */
  background-color: #999999;
  line-height: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

As a side note, you have duplicate `text-align: center` values in your original CSS.

[Ordering your CSS properties](https://css-tricks.com/poll-results-how-do-you-order-your-css-properties/) in a consistent way (for instance, I like to alphabetize my CSS properties, but in the example above also grouped them by type) will help you avoid potentially hard-to-find bugs or duplicate properties.

Answer (score -1):

Is there enough content to fill up 100vh? You can just set your footer to fill that space if not, or set your body `height` or `min-height`

I recommend a flexbox layout where the footer does not expand but rather the main content but here is what you are looking for:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  background-color: blue;
}

footer {
  flex: 1 auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <p>Hi in the header</p>
  </header>
  <main>
    <p>Hi in the main</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Hi in the footer</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: OP is asking about width, not height.